# Caching git diff results

Tags: git, caching, diff

I have a fairly large git repository on which I need to run repeated `git diff` commands.

For example I need the output of `git diff --shortstat commit1 commit2` as well as that of `git diff --diff-filter=ad --shortstat commit1 commit2`.

1. Is there a way of either caching the `diff` results in the background to make the repeated invokation (with different options) faster or alternatively,
2. is there a way of running some alternative more universal `git diff` command from which I can derive the two results inexpensively?

*Nb. I saw there is a `git diff --cached` option, but from what I understand this does something entirely different.*

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2873039/3691891) would help.